# jquery find and replace text, without element id

Tags: jquery, find, replace

I'm playing around with finding and replacing text.

The only problem I'm having is finding a text string, that is not attached to an element with an ID.  Otherwise, it would be easy.

I'm trying something like this:

```
$("*").each(function () {
    $(this).html(this.html().replace('Original Text','New Text'));
});
```

Not working too well.
Anyone run into this before?

Also, if I have several words or phrases to find and replace, how does that affect the speed/processing power of the user's browser?  Is it a memory hog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Takpar, your code works too.  It seems to stop a few other things from working, but only items I'm pulling dynamically.  For example, when I'm using `.ajax()`.  Not sure why, but that's why I ran into.  I'll test more.

On a related topic, Gumbo's code works:

```
$("*").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Subject:','Name:'));
    }
});
```

The only thing I'm running into issues with is replacing text that is loaded after the page loads.

I do have some javascript functions that are displaying data from the server, but only after the page has loaded all elements.  For example, a user selects a value from a dropdown that initiates an event to load a list of products from the database.

I format some of those products like this:

```
Granny Smith Apples
Price: x.xx per pound
Nutritional facts....
```

I will only want to find a replace the word "Price:", and possibly replace it with "Cost:".

But as I mentioned, that data has not been loaded yet.

Is a limit I have to live with?

Comment: this works well in modern browsers I passed this through JS Lint and it said you were missing one `=` equal sign, so i added it. How can i make this compatible with IE8 -IE7 ? @coffeemonitor @jellybelly

Answer (score 21):

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("old", "new");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

why don't you simply use:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('Original Text','New Text'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `:contains()` selector. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("*:contains('Original Text')").each(...);
```

Comment: `:contains` is not a good idea: “The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, *in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof*.”

Comment: Only true if you don't want to replace it in descendants.

Comment: Meaning, the replace method is going to do the replacing, not the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("*").each(function () { 
if ($(this).children().length == 0){ 
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Old String/g, "New String"));
}});
```