# Replace text with {} symbol in Jerry?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jodd, jodd-lagarto

I have the following code:

```
              <p>
                To
                <br>
            {customerDetails}
              </p>
```

I tried by following but it gave an error.

```
    Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(FileUtil.readString(file));
doc.$("#customerDetails").text(ci.name + "&lt;BR/&gt;" + ci.addr1);
```

Here the text which will be replaced by {customerDetails} should be independent, thats why i do not want to take any help of tags. If i give any tag for {customerDetails}, "To" will be distrubed.

I want to replace the "{customerDetails}" with some text without take any help of html tags or css classes and id's.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but that's a very vague question.  Are there any other instances of {text} on the page anywhere?  It *must* be in a container that you can use to identify it, either by class or ID, so what's it in?  You've given us very little information to go on.  Also, what have you already tried?  This isn't a site to say, "Write my code"

Comment: a damn costly solution http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36Yjh/1/

Comment: Please review qeustion, it has been edited.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu post code to show what you have tried....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find text(A) and replace it with text(B) + HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365582/find-texta-and-replace-it-with-textb-html)

Comment: You don't need to give the {customerName} text a class or ID - you should give a class or ID to the paragraph tag that contains it, as that's what you have to modify - the text within it.

Comment: yes you are right but i have other static text is there (TO)

Comment: Yes - I know.  What I said still stands.  Look at my answer below to see what I mean - it changes the {customerName} text without changing anything else.

Comment: i have given complete details now, will it be possible to upvoted my question?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with the answer I've supplied, as it does do exactly what you have asked?

Comment: it is fine, but as i am using that in my jodd-jerry code which is diff in syntax, it is not taking "i" and "html"

Comment: Hey guys, this is **not** a javascript question. The tag was wrong and I removed it. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is *not* a javascript question, but Java question. It's about [Jodd Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/), parsing library in Java that looks very similar to jQuery. So all jsfiddle solutions here does not help, and I believe some negative scores on this question are not ok.

Anyway, the @Archer solution is one that can you give a good direction. Here is the java version of the same:

```
Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry("<p>to<br>{customerDetails}</p>");

doc.$("p").each(new JerryFunction() {
    public boolean onNode(Jerry $this, int index) {
        String innerHtml = $this.html();
        innerHtml = StringUtil.replace(
            innerHtml, "{customerDetails}", "Jodd <b>rocks</b>");
        $this.html(innerHtml);
        return true;
    }
});

String newHtml = doc.html();
assertEquals("<p>to<br>Jodd <b>rocks</b></p>", newHtml);
```

Jerry still does not have `html(function)` type of method implemented (it's on todo), so you have to use `each` explicitly.

Note that you can not search for `#customerDetails` as you don't have any DOM element with this ID. What you could do instead, is to have an empty placeholder `div` or a `span` like this:

```
<p>to<br><span id="#custdet">{customerDetails}</span></p>
```

and then you would be able to do something like you wrote in the question.

Anyway, I would try to solve this in a different way, if possible. If you already have a marker and HTML content, can you simply replace it without parsing?

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you for clarifying all the users. I got a solution for query like below, Please let me know if this approach is bad.                                                                   Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(FileUtil.readString(file));

 String replaced = doc.$("body, p").html().replace("{customerDetails}", "<b>" + ci.name + "</b>" + "<BR />" + ci.addr1);
     doc.$("body, p").html(replaced);
String processedHtml = doc.html();

Comment: That would work (remove comma in CSS query) except it can be more optimized: 1) you are using `replace` that uses regexp - use `StringUtil.replace()` instead; 2) don't lookup twice, assign `doc.$("body p")` to a variable and reuse it.

Comment: Ok i will do that, according to your answer for each 'p' tag will it replace?

Comment: I have only one {customerDetails} in my html, Is it good to loop through all the 'p' in the html file.

Comment: No. In fact, do not parse html at all, just replace token ;)

Comment: can i do more than one replacement using above each method, i have other 'p' tag with '{printBodyHtml}'.

Comment: Sure. Just try to do it with less parsing as possible :)

Comment: but once {customerDetails} is replaced first and it is also replaced while replacing {printBodyTemplate}. Is it good approach?

Comment: Instead i am using doc.$("body"), Please let me know if not good

Comment: Sorry, but that all depends on your use case and your goal, its hard to discuss that like this. In general, you should avoid multiple parsing and try to find the minimal string that contains replacement target. Moreover, this starts to be off topic :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work with your exact html above...

```
$("p").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace("{customerDetails}", ci.name + "<br />" + ci.addr1);
});
```

If there are other paragraph tags in the page then it will run against them as well.  As I commented above, we really need more information to give you a good answer, rather than just an answer.

**[jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/X3qr9/)**

Comment: @GonçaloVieira Not unless there's a good reason to, and with the question as it stands there isn't one.

Comment: This will only do 1 replacement, so any other {customerDetails} are ignored.

Comment: it should be :  return html.replace(/{customerDetails}/ig, "Mr. John Kramer");

Comment: Yes @Steve - it will only do 1 replacement, which is exactly what I intended. As already explained above, I'm not using a regular expression because the question does not require one.