# Simple javascript find and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

is there a straightforward method for searching within a div for a specific string and replacing it with another? I cannot use .replaceWith alone because there are other elements within the div I need to preserve. I've tried various javascript methods found here to no avail.

So something like:

```
$('#foo').find('this string').replaceWith('this other string');
```

for:

```
<div id="foo"><div id="child">Other Element</div>this string</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349138/jquery-find-and-replace-text-without-element-id/2349208#2349208

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foo = $('#foo').html();

foo = foo.replace('this string', 'this other string');

$('#foo').html(foo);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/w9GzF/

Comment: "there are other elements within the div I need to preserve" -- this would not be suitable

Comment: This doesn't work if you have multiple occurrences of 'this string'.

Comment: setting the `html(..)` like that will re-create DOM elements, meaning you would lose out on any previously attached data or events on those elements.

Comment: @Anurag i see no other way to do it. to preserve the handlers, i would say to use `live()`

Comment: @Neal I believe HTML rewriting is harmful.

Comment: @pac, remember to select an `accepted answer` when you can :-D

Comment: Yea, you could definitely use `live()` or `delegate()`.  I've done this exact scenario and it's what I had to do.

Comment: @Neal - the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349138/jquery-find-and-replace-text-without-element-id/2349208#2349208) shows one way to do it. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/A2WAb/2/).

Comment: @Sime, yes, that was my original thought, but that could also screw up the html, see (deleted answer)

Comment: @Neal That answer is doing it wrong. Retrieving the text content with `text()` will remove all child elements. That's not what I said which is: walk the DOM and execute `replace()` on every Text node.

Answer (score 9):

This replaces all occurrences:

```
var $foo = $('#foo'),
    fooHtml = $foo.html();

$foo.html(fooHtml.replace(/this string/g, 'this other string'));
```

Comment: what is? my answer or the comments on your answer?

Comment: it is the same answer as mine, but yet has more `up`s

Comment: because it's correct? you got the check mark and yours doesn't even replace every occurrence of 'this string'. what do you care?

Answer (score 3):

Just using html().replace() with match all results element attribute or tag name.

I face this issue also, my solution is similar to findAndReplace() function from http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/ but using regular expression to get all textNode and search in each of them.

```
function epubSearch(query) {
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var re = new RegExp(query, "gi");//pattern for keyword
    var re0 = new RegExp("[>][^><]*[><]", "gi");//pattern to get textnode

    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML.replace(re0, function (text) {
        // with each textNode, looking for keyword
        return text.replace(re, "<span class=\"search-result\" style=\"background-color:red;\">$&</span>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery plugin I just wrote that provides `safeReplace` for collections.

```
(function($){

$.fn.safeReplace = function ( find, replacement ) {

    return this.each(function(index, elem) {

        var
            queue = [elem],
            node,
            i;

        while (queue.length) {

            node = queue.shift();

            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                i = node.childNodes.length;
                while (i--) {
                    queue[queue.length] = node.childNodes[i];
                }
            } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace( find, replacement );
            }
        }

    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

And here's how you use it:

```
$('#foo').safeReplace( /this string/g, 'something else' );
```

I've only tested in FF 4, and only on the sample HTML input - more testing is recommended.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [String.replace();](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)?

e.g.

```
$("#div").html($("#div").html().replace("search string", "replace string"));
```

Or Exploded:

```
var $divElement = $("#div");         //Find the div to perform replace on
var divContent = $divElement.html(); //Get the div's content
divContent = divContent.replace("search string", "replace string"); //Perform replace
$divElement.html(divContent);        //Replace contents of div element.
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works as many times as your term appears and will not kill any of the important things that shouldn't be changed (stored in the excludes array).

usage: `findAndReplace('dog','cat', document.getElementById('content'));`

```
/* js find andreplace Based on http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/ */

function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
    return;
}
var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
            new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
    childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes,
    cnLength = childNodes.length,
    excludes = ['html','head','style','link','meta','script','object','iframe'];
while (cnLength--) {
    var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
    if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
      excludes.indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
      arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
    }
    if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
        continue;
    }
    var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
        frag = (function(){
            var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            wrap.innerHTML = html;
            while (wrap.firstChild) {
                frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
            }
            return frag;
        })();
    parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
    parent.removeChild(currentNode);
}
}
```