# Use jQuery to find and replace multiple words on the page

Tags: jquery, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find and Replace more than 1 word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910819/find-and-replace-more-than-1-word)

I want to use jQuery to replace all instances of specific words. For example, I want to replace "My Classes" to "My Levels" and "My Class" to "My Level". I also want to change "college" to "university"

Comment: Searching this forum gave me: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349446/jquery-find-and-replace-text-after-body-was-loaded 
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349138/jquery-find-and-replace-text-without-element-id

Comment: I've tried other examples, but they all just replace one word (X with Y) and I have need to replace multiple sets of words (X with Y, A with B, 1 with 2, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var dictionary= {
"My Classes":"My Levels",
"My Class":"My Level",
"college":"university"
};

$("body *").each( function(){
    for( var ptrn in dictionary){
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(new RegExp(ptrn ,"g"), dictionary[ptrn] ) );
    }
});
```