# jQuery replace function strips html

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension to manipulate a web page that I do not have control over, so I can't edit the existing css classes and html code. Based on the following example, I am trying to insert text in between two words within a paragraph:

```
<p class="abc">
<b>Title:</b>The Second Title
<br>
<b>Author:</b>Mary White
<br>
<b>Date:</b>2004
</p>
<p class="abc">
<b>Title:</b>The First Title
<br>
<b>Author:</b>John Smith
<br>
<b>Date:</b>2003
</p>
```

I have a list of names like:

Mary White -> Mary B. White

John Smith -> John L. Smith

I need to replace the first and last name with the full name ie:
John Smith -> John L. Smith

I tried the following:

```
$(".abc:contains('Mary White')").text(function () {
  return $(this).text().replace("Mary White", "Mary B. White");
});
```

but that removes the `<b>` and `<br>` html tags.

I also tried this:

```
$(".htp:contains('John Smith')").replaceWith("John L. Smith");
```

but that replaces the entire p and replaces it with the full name. How can I get it to display the paragraph with the name containing the middle initial?

Comment: It's not directly what you are looking at, but this is close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349138/jquery-find-and-replace-text-without-element-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) removes the tags and just gives you the text.

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), but your code will fail if there is any html markup in the name.

Answer (score 1):

This is might be what you want:

```
$(function() {
    $(".abc").each(function(idx, elm) {
        elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replace("Mary White", "Mary B. White");
    });
});​
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DVex7/)